# Bison syntax error unexpected $undefined expecting $end error

Tags: c, parsing, bison

Hi I have started leaning Bison parser generator. I tried the following program. I compiled and running the program using `MinGW on Window 7`, with `mintty` client terminal. Bison version is 2.4.2

```
%verbose
%error-verbose

%{

   #include <cstdio>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <ctype.h>

   int yylex(void);
   int yyerror(const char *msg);

%}

%token INT

%%

rule   :  
         INT { $$ = $1; printf("value : %d %d %d %d\n", $1, 
               @1.first_line, @1.first_column, @1.last_column); }
       ;

%%

int main()
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int yylex()
{
   char ch = getchar();
   if(isdigit(ch)) 
   { 
      ungetc(ch, stdin);
      scanf("%d", &yylval);
      return INT;
   }
   return ch;
}

int yyerror(const char *msg)
{
   printf("Error : %s\n", msg);
}
```

I compiled the program with `bison filename.y` then `gcc filename.tab.c` and when I try to run the program and enter 5 in stdin, I am getting the following error as it is printed from yyerror function. Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong.

```
Error : syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end
```

Comment: I recommend to use flex as lexer. Bison and flex complement each other very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your lexer reads the `\n` (newline) character after the number you entered, it returns it to your parser, which doesn't recognize it as anything, so you get the `unexpected $undefined` (the newline is printed as `$undefined` as newlines never appear in your grammar), when it is expecting `$end` (end of input indicator).

Change the last line of your `yylex` to `return 0;` (0 is the end of input indicator) instead of `return ch;` and it should work.